# Memory leakage Autodesk Vault Server

Tags: memory, sql-server, autodesk-inventor

We have an HP proliant 360 G6 server with Server 2008 R2 Standard. This OS unfortunately comes with the 32GB memory cap. I will be replacing this server within the year however in the meantime I am dealing with an incredible memory leak on the SQL instance; MSSQL AUTODESKVAULT. The SQL database in (unfortunately) contained in a direct access storage RAID 5 array w/ 4x 600GB 10K SAS discs.

The leakage will cause the memory usage to go from approx 9/32GB to 20/32 and the only reason I can see is our one user that has Inventor installed on Windows 10 pulls a model as small as 500MB or 1GB out of the AUTODESK VAULT SQL database.

Is there anything I can check or do to prevent this incredible memory allocation from jumping like this? I realize the usage may creep up for a few seconds or even min while its pulling the drawing/model but to stay that high seems wrong. ANY advice is appreciated!

[image: memory leakage jump doubles in 3 seconds due to windows 10 user opening 600MB model out of VAULT server database via SQL]

Comment: Although counterintuitive, this might be normal behavior. Did you contact Autodesk on the matter? What process is using the memory?

Comment: I have no contacted Autodesk that is my next step. In the past contacting them has been a fruitless endeavor for me.

The process hogging all the memory is sqlserv.exe w/ service MSSQL$AUTODESKVAULT

Comment: This isn't a memory leak, its a feature :) In SQL Management Studio you can change the memory allocation and max. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191144%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I know how to change the max. If this is normal I wouldn't want to limit it. Even if it does seem like so much memory. The new server will be allocated approx 128GB memory... then it can have what it wants!!!